# Постраничная навигация

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Недавно начала заниматься php, вот, никак не могу понять, как в этом коде появляется переменная page, как php узнает, на какой странице мы сейчас находимся?

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT str FROM options", $db);
$myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$num = $myrow1["str"];
// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу
@$page = $_GET['page'];
// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bonus");
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$posts = $temp[0];
// Находим общее число страниц
$total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
$total =  intval($total);
// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы
$page = intval($page);
// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно
// переходим на первую страницу
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
  if($page > $total) $page = $total;
// Вычисляем начиная с какого номера
// следует выводить сообщения
$start = $page * $num - $num;
// Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start

$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bonus ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $num", $db);

$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад
if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=bonus1.php?page=1>Первая</a> | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>Предыдущая</a> | ';
// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед
if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>Следующая</a> | <a href=bonus1.php?page=' .$total. '>Последняя</a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть
if($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 5) .'>'. ($page - 5) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 4) .'>'. ($page - 4) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 3) .'>'. ($page - 3) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | ';

if($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 5) .'>'. ($page + 5) .'</a>';
if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 4) .'>'. ($page + 4) .'</a>';
if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 3) .'>'. ($page + 3) .'</a>';
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

// Вывод меню если страниц больше одной

if ($total > 1)
{
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
echo "<div class=\"pstrnav\">";
echo $pervpage.$page5left.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$page5right.$nextpage;
echo "</div>";
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: @Регина, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы показали, называется постраничной навигацией. 
Цитата: *как php узнает на какой странице мы сейчас находимся?* 
Так вот же, как у вас ссылки формируются:

```
<a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 5) .'>
```

Передается параметр **page** с номером страницы методом GET.

Answer (score 2):

Немного перепишу код.
то что я поменял - перед меняемой строкой добавил 
`///`

```
<?php

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT str FROM options", $db);
$myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$num = $myrow1["str"];
// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу
/// @$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = @$_GET['page']; // @ - "глушение" вывода ошибки, только вот @ нужно ставить перед $_GET а не перед $page
// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bonus");
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$posts = $temp[0];
// Находим общее число страниц
/// $total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
/// $total =  intval($total);

$total = ceil($posts / $num); // ceil - целое число с округление в большую сторону. Аналогичная функция floor - округляет в меньшую сторону
/// например
/// ceil(5.1); // 6
/// floor(5.9) // 5

// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы
$page = intval($page);

// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно
// переходим на первую страницу
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
if($page > $total) $page = $total;
// Вычисляем начиная с какого номера
// следует выводить сообщения
$start = $page * $num - $num;
// Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start

$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bonus ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $num", $db);

$myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

/// то что ниже - это полный капец...
/*

// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад
if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=bonus1.php?page=1>Первая</a> | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>Предыдущая</a> | ';
// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед
if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>Следующая</a> | <a href=bonus1.php?page=' .$total. '>Последняя</a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть
if($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 5) .'>'. ($page - 5) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 4) .'>'. ($page - 4) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 3) .'>'. ($page - 3) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a> | ';
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a> | ';

if($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 5) .'>'. ($page + 5) .'</a>';
if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 4) .'>'. ($page + 4) .'</a>';
if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 3) .'>'. ($page + 3) .'</a>';
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href=bonus1.php?page='. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';

// Вывод меню если страниц больше одной

if ($total > 1)
{
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
echo "<div class=\"pstrnav\">";
echo $pervpage.$page5left.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left.'<b>'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$page5right.$nextpage;
echo "</div>";
}

*/

/// немного перепишу.
if ($total > 1) {
    $navLinks = array();
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if ($page != 1) { // если мы не на первой странице - добавляем ссылку "в начало"
        $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'">В начало</a>';
        $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'?page='.($page - 1).'">Предыдущая</a>';
    }

    for ($i = 5 ; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $p = $page - $i;
        if ($p > 0) {
            $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'?page='.($p).'">'.$p.'</a>';
        }
    }

    $navLinks[] = $page;

    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $p = $page + $i;
        if ($p < $total) {
            $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'?page='.($p).'">'.$p.'</a>';
        }
    }

    if ($page != $total) {
        $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'?page='.($page + 1).'">Следующая</a>';
        $navLinks[] = '<a href="'.$link.'?page='.$total.'">Последняя</a>';
    }
}

echo '<div class="pstrnav">';
echo join ('&nbsp;|&nbsp;', $navLinks);
echo '</div>';
```